# Updating a CloudFormation stack if codebase updates

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

So I have an existing CloudFormation stack up and running. However, I haven't found a solution for my problem, which is that I want my resources, for example EC2 and Lambda, to have up to date code.

It seems that a CloudFormation stack doesn't update if the template doesn't have any changes. I'm holding my code inside a S3 bucket as a zip-file, but if this file gets changed, CloudFormation doesn't notice it.

Is my best bet creating a git hook script that uses AWS CLI and updates the EC2 and Lambda code or is there some 'elegant' way for CloudFormation to notice these changes?

Comment: You should consider the [serverless framework](https://serverless.com/). It handles all of this behind the scenes for you. At the very least you can take a peek at what it's doing in the `.serverless` folder. You should find all the CloudFormation templates there.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new lambda function to update your existing lambda and ec2 or call the cloud formation to update them. On your S3, create an object Put event and call that new lambda function. So whenever a new file(zip) is put in s3, your ec2 & lambda gets updated.